# Improve ANT Ivy build process

Tags: java, ant, build, ivy

I have a project setup with apache-ant Ivy. The project has several modules like

commons,user,order,billing,reports and so on. I need to improve the build process. I am new to ANT Ivy.

**Background**

Module compiling sequence is defined in the main build.xml in as a 
macro definition.

```
 <macrodef name="components">
    <attribute name="target" />
    <sequential>
        commons,user,order,billing,reports
    </sequential>
```

Technologies of the project are spring 2.5 , hibernate3.5 , struts2. 
The project maintains a repository of jars.

i.  cache (Project module.jars , external jars like spring)

ii. external (external jars like spring,hibernate,jdom)

iii. internal(project module jars)

Final build deploy as a war to the application server. This project has a big code base.

To compile it takes around 9 minutes.

I need to reduce the build time , improve the build process. Please advice me with

```
 a. suitable possible approaches

 b. checklist and possible tools
```

that I can use to analyse time consuming places and improve the build time.

Comment: Something specific for quick start of analysis: http://greensopinion.blogspot.in/2009/12/ant-build-analysis-gets-facelift.html

Comment: Thanks. I think this is not active https://antutility.dev.java.net/site/

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072134/java-app-dev/incremental-and-fast-builds-using-ant.html

Comment: For antutility see => https://github.com/dgreen99/antutility